# why neither document or window is defined

Tags: javascript

When I try to run my code in a browser it will just load forever or it tells me  that the page is not answering, Ive got no idea why, help would be much appriciated! My compiler also tells me that window in window.onload is not defined and that document is not defined.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");





    var sphere = {

        diameter : 300,
    }
    function drawSphere(resolution){

         var size = resolution;
         var diameter = sphere.diameter;
         var j = 0;



        var langd = diameter/2;
        var bredd = 0;
        var radie = diameter/2;

        c.fillStyle = "gray";

        var y;
            for(y = 0; 0 < diameter; y += size){




            var startX = radie - bredd/2;
            var slutX = radie + bredd/2;

            var x;
                for(x = startX; x < slutX; x += size){

                c.beginPath();
                c.fillRect(x, y, x + size,y + size);
                c.closePath();

            }

        j = j + 1;
        langd = langd - size*j;
        bredd = Math.sqrt(radie*radie - langd*langd);
        }

    }

    function init(){
        drawSphere(2);
    }

    init();
};
```

Comment: `My compiler also tells me` what compiler?

Comment: `for(y = 0; 0 < diameter; y += size){` — when will `0 < diameter` *not* be true? Nothing in the loop changes the diameter.

Comment: ^^^ That's the bug right there. Stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Also, how are you loading the script? It might be running before the DOM finishes rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(y = 0; 0 < diameter; y += size){
```

You put zero here instead of y.

```
for(y = 0; y < diameter; y += size){
```

This works, although drawing is a bit off.

Edit: I gave you a fish, but I should give you a rod as well.
For the future, you can solve this kind of problems using developer tools in a browser. Under "Sources" tab ("Debugger" in Firefox) you have a pause button which will stop the execution at the line which is currently processing.